# Set a default content from database in react-draft-wysiwyg editor

Tags: reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am creating a blog website in which I am embedding react-draft-wysiwyg editor. I am facing problem when the user has to update the blog. When I click the update button the content is gone. I looked into many solutions but I couldn't make it work.

This is my code

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../../context/Context";
import "./singlePost.css";
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertFromHTML } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import { convertToHTML } from 'draft-convert';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

export default function SinglePost() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const path = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const PF = "http://localhost:5000/images/";
  const { user } = useContext(Context);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [updateMode, setUpdateMode] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPost = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/posts/" + path);
      setPost(res.data);
      setTitle(res.data.title);
      setDesc(res.data.desc);
    };
    getPost();
  }, [path]);

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/posts/${post._id}`, {
        data: { username: user.username },
      });
      window.location.replace("/");
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  // updating post
  const handleUpdate = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.put(`/posts/${post._id}`, {
        username: user.username,
        title,
        desc,
      });
      setUpdateMode(false)
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    () => EditorState.createWithContent(
      ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        convertFromHTML(desc)
      )
    ),
  );
  const  [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);
  const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state);
    convertContentToHTML();
  }
  const convertContentToHTML = () => {
    let currentContentAsHTML = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    setConvertedContent(currentContentAsHTML);
    setDesc(currentContentAsHTML);
  }
  const createMarkup = (html) => {
    return  {
      __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(html)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="singlePost">
      <div className="singlePostWrapper">
        {post.photo && (
          <img src={PF + post.photo} alt="" className="singlePostImg" />
        )}
        {updateMode ? (
          <input
            type="text"
            value={title}
            className="singlePostTitleInput"
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
        ) : (
          <h1 className="singlePostTitle">
            {title}
            {post.username === user?.username && (
              <div className="singlePostEdit">
                <i
                  className="singlePostIcon far fa-edit"
                  onClick={() => setUpdateMode(true)}
                ></i>
                <i
                  className="singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt"
                  onClick={handleDelete}
                ></i>
              </div>
            )}
          </h1>
        )}
        <div className="singlePostInfo">
          <span className="singlePostAuthor">
            Author:
            <Link to={`/?user=${post.username}`} className="link">
              <b> {post.username}</b>
            </Link>
          </span>
          <span className="singlePostDate">
            {new Date(post.createdAt).toDateString()}
          </span>
        </div>
        {updateMode ? (
          // <textarea
          //   className="singlePostDescInput"
          //   value={desc}
          //   onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
          // />
          <Editor
            contentState={desc}
            editorState={editorState}
            onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
            wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
            editorClassName="editor-class"
            toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
          />
        ) : (
          <p className="singlePostDesc">{Parser(desc)}</p>
        )}
        {updateMode && (
          <button className="singlePostButton" onClick={handleUpdate}>
            Update
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to display `desc` which is saved in MongoDB database when the user clicks on update button.
The following part is what I tried to do but didn't work.

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    () => EditorState.createWithContent(
      ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        convertFromHTML(desc)
      )
    ),
  );
```

I am getting warning in this:
react.development.js:220 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the r component.

Please help

Comment: same issue here...

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I am also facing the same problem